# How do I prove that these are orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Prove that for any $m\times n$ matrix $A$, there is n orthogonal basis $\mathcal B=(\vec v_1,\ldots, \vec v_n)$ of $\Bbb R^n$ such that the vectors $A\vec v_1,\ldots, A\vec v_n$ are orthogonal. Note that some of the vectors $A\vec v_i$ may be $\vec 0$. (Hint: use the Spectral Theorem on the symmetric matrix $A^TA$).

My attempt: for any n x m matrix A, there has to be an basis consisting of at least n vectors. Therefore, we can make an orthonormal basis v1...vn using the gram-schmidt process. From here we know that at least two of these vectors are orthogonal - by definition.

Is my proof okay?

Answer (score 3):

Your proof is not ok in this form: Note that Gram Schmidt will not allow you to make the $v_i$ and the $Av_i$ orthogonal at the same time.

Why not follow the hint?
The matrix $A^TA$ is symmetric, hence permits an orthogonal basis $\mathcal B=(v_1,\ldots, v_n)$ of eigenvectors. So the first condition is already fulfilled. But we also have for $i\ne j$ that
$$\langle Av_i,Av_j\rangle = v_i^TA^TAv_j=v_i^T\lambda_jv_j=\lambda_j\langle v_i,v_j\rangle = 0 $$
as desired.